# Boostrap's popover only displaying title and stops working after first toggle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

So I'm really stumped here because I am literally using the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/popovers/)'s example and it is simply refusing to work.
I have

1. Imported Boostrap
2. Imported Popover
3. Initialised Tooltips
4. Initialised Popover

All as per the documentation.

I have then added the following code to tryout popovers:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-bs-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

This is the same code as on the documentation, the popup shows, but incorrectly, it only displays the title and not the content. And once the first Toggle is completed aka, once you show and then hide the popover, it doesn't show again.

[Screenshot of  what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM2Uo.png)

By the way here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" defer></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="./assets/scripts/init-tooltips.js" defer></script>
      <script src="./assets/scripts/init-popover.js" defer></script>

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

      <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">About me</a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="./index.html">Introduction</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="./life.html">Life</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
               <a class="nav-link" href="./life.html">Education</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
            </li>
         </div>
      </nav>
   </head>
   <body>
        <h1 class="center">Education</h1>
        <figure class="center">
           <img src=./assets/images/1.jpeg>
           <img src=./assets/images/2.jpeg>
           <img src=./assets/images/3.jpeg>
           <img src=./assets/images/4.jpeg>
           <img src=./assets/images/5.jpeg>
        </figure>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-bs-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
      <p>test</p>
   </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you're using `data-bs-popover` and `data-bs-content` on the button and that is Bootstrap 5 formatting.

You are calling Bootstrap 4 with

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3...........</script>
```

Use `data-popover` and `data-content` for Bootstrap 4.

Comment: aaah! thank you! I'm doing the Harvard's Cs50 course and they gave us a pre-filled in HTML file with blank spaces to fill in. However all the documentation is for bootstrap 5! All working Now! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the easier way then is to call v5 instead of v4 if all your content is formatted that way. Generally speaking you just have to remember to insert the `-bs-` in the middle for the formatting if any does end up out of place.